# lower accuracy is not reflected in AUC in biased data set?

Tags: machine-learning

```
X_train = {my training data features}
y_train = {my training data truth}


kf = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=42, shuffle=True)
score = cross_val_score(SVC(), X_train, y_train, scoring = 'accuracy', cv = kf, n_jobs = -1)
```

gives this:
`array([1.        , 0.98717949, 1.        , 1.        , 0.98701299])`

I run this code to get AUC:

```
tprs = []
aucs = []
mean_fpr = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
i = 0
for train, test in kf.split(npX_train):
    model = SVC(probability=True).fit(npX_train[train], npy_train[train])
    probas_ = model.predict_proba(npX_train[test])
    # Compute ROC curve and area the curve
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(npy_train[test], probas_[:, 1])
    tprs.append(interp(mean_fpr, fpr, tpr))
    tprs[-1][0] = 0.0
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
    aucs.append(roc_auc)
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, lw=1, alpha=0.3,
             label='ROC fold %d (AUC = %0.2f)' % (i, roc_auc))

    i += 1
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], linestyle='--', lw=2, color='r',
         label='Chance', alpha=.8)


mean_tpr = np.mean(tprs, axis=0)
mean_tpr[-1] = 1.0
mean_auc = auc(mean_fpr, mean_tpr)
std_auc = np.std(aucs)
plt.plot(mean_fpr, mean_tpr, color='b',
         label=r'Mean ROC (AUC = %0.2f $\pm$ %0.2f)' % (mean_auc, std_auc),
         lw=2, alpha=.8)

std_tpr = np.std(tprs, axis=0)
tprs_upper = np.minimum(mean_tpr + std_tpr, 1)
tprs_lower = np.maximum(mean_tpr - std_tpr, 0)
plt.fill_between(mean_fpr, tprs_lower, tprs_upper, color='grey', alpha=.2,
                 label=r'$\pm$ 1 std. dev.')

plt.xlim([-0.01, 1.01])
plt.ylim([-0.01, 1.01])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate',fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate',fontsize=18)
plt.title('Cross-Validation ROC of SVM',fontsize=18)
plt.legend(loc="lower right", prop={'size': 15})
plt.show()
```

which gives me this:

[image]

but if I get a confusion matrix for each iteration:

```
for train, test in kf.split(npX_train):
    model = SVC(probability=True).fit(npX_train[train], npy_train[train])

    # make confusion matrix plot for iteration
    y_pred = model.predict(npX_train[test])
    cm = confusion_matrix(npy_train[test], y_pred)
    cm_display = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(cm).plot()
    plot_confusion_matrix(model, npX_train[test], npy_train[test])
    plt.plot()
```

The accuracy for label 1, which I care about does not look that great. Of the 22 true label 1, seems to get it right 20 times out of all runs.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

My questions are:

1. Did I mess up that AUC plot or is that slight bend in the blue mean ROC line reflecting the inaccuracy of the model?
2. Is there a better way to evaluate accuracy for a biased input where I care about the accurate prediction of the more rare event?

Comment: By which criterion 22 correctly classified samples out of 24 in total is not satisfactory? Plus, all the results you show (accuracy, AUC, confusion matrices) are consistent., so it is quite unclear what your exact question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For biased or imbalanced datasets use the metric F1 score. F1 score uses precision and recall.

Read for more detail on f1 score
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/accuracy-vs-f1-score-6258237beca2

Sklearn
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html

Comment: Do people typically report mean F1 then (and maybe standard deviation), for example I get these values from my five fold cross validation : [1.        , 0.8       , 1.        , 1.        , 0.88888889], would it be normal to report mean f1 of .94?

Comment: Yeah makes sense to take avg if using cross validation. I normally just use train test split so I get back one score but that's just a personal preference.